# AWS SDK in Go does not take region information from profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Trying to follow the official [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/s3-example-basic-bucket-operations.html) for listing buckets

```golang
    sess, err := session.NewSessionWithOptions(session.Options{
        Profile: "my-profile",
    })

    if err != nil {
        exitErrorf("Unable to create session, %v", err)
    }

    // Create S3 service client
    svc := s3.New(sess)
    result, err := svc.ListBuckets(nil)
    if err != nil {
        exitErrorf("Unable to list buckets, %v", err)
    }
```

Note that `my-profile` (residing in `~/.aws/credentials` ) has region information associated

```
[my-profile]
aws_access_key_id=XXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key=XXXXXXX
region=us-east-1
```

The program fails as follows:

```
Unable to list buckets, MissingRegion: could not find region configuration
exit status 1
```

**edit**: managed to work my way around this by prepending this line of code

```
os.Setenv("AWS_REGION", "us-east-1")
```

but I guess the proper way should be for the SDK to read the profile appropriately, no?

Comment: You might want to simply use `~/.aws/config` as it can store both config and credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[region is set](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html) in `~/.aws/config`.

~/.aws/config

```
[my-profile]
region=us-east-1
```

~/.aws/credentials

```
[my-profile]
aws_access_key_id=XXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key=XXXXXXX
```